# How to login website with username and password using windows (XP) batch script

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-xp

I am able to connect website using batch file but I don't know how to insert username & password into it and of course a click on submit button.

Also i would like to know how to click buttons available on sites (ex. export in xls option)  using windows batch script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With batch I can't think of a way. With VBScript, it's easy. Create a new text file and name it AutomateIE.vbs and add the following code. Double click it to run it.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "http://TheWebsite"
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Set ipf = IE.document.all.username
ipf.Value = "Username" 
Set ipf = IE.document.all.password
ipf.Value = "Password" 
Set ipf = IE.document.all.Submit
ipf.Click 
IE.Quit
```

Make sure username and password are the actual names defined in the website or it won't work. Change them to whatever they should be. If you post the URL, I can verify them.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the alternative suggested by you. It's really very helpful. I don't know the VB scripting at all ... But I tried and it works. Can you please suggest code if after login I will click on export:excel tab and i want to save file with particular name.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Not without having access to the site so I can see the HTML code.

Comment: I can not pulled out the code from client web site . Thanks anyways ..  :)

Comment: Hi may i get your email id so that i can mail you the sample code... Thanxs

Comment: For anyone getting error on all.Submit my problem was that my submit-button didn't have an id. Changing the id of the button to submit helped me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) utility. It is not native to Windows, but is available for Windows, and allows fetching files from arbitrary URLs, even with security.

Logging in will usually involve the creation of a session cookie. Both utilities have mechanisms for storing session cookies between invocations of the tool, and clearing the cookies when done.

Button clicking is often just the UI provided for HTML form submission. In those cases, you create a file containing the data to be submitted and provided it to the utility when it fetches the correct URL. Figuring out that URL requires parsing and understanding the HTML of the page.

Many pages are built with interactive features, where buttons are used only to trigger script actions. Driving that sort of site from a batch file is likely not possible since it inherently assumes an interactive user. In that case, you either drive an interactive browser through an automation API as suggested by [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198850/68204) or by automation with the browser itself, perhaps by using GreaseMonkey with Firefox.

You will need to get [wget from the GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) project, which provides Windows ports of many interesting tools and utilities that originate in Unix.

An alternative to `wget` is [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) which has a very similar set of features and is also available for Windows.

Comment: wget and cURL both not worked on windows XP command prompt.